# An example for totally disconnected but not totally separated spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set with the discrete topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{disc}}$ and the cofinite topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{cof}}$, and we define a topology on $Y = X \cup  \{0,1\}$ as $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{disc}} \cup \{U\cup V\colon U\in\{0,1,\{0,1\}\},V\in\mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{cof}}\}$.

Could you please prove that $(Y,\mathcal{T})$ is totally disconnected but not totally separated?

Comment: Please add details indicating what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we prove $Y$ is totally disconnected.
For any $y_1,y_2\in Y$, there are three possibles we need to consider, namely $y_1,y_2\in X$, $y_1,y_2\in\{0,1\}$ and $y_1\in X,y_2\in\{0,1\}$.
If $x_1,x_2\in X$, they are not in the same connected component, since $\{x_1\},\{x_2\}$ are disjoint open sets under the subspace topology of any subspace $A\subset Y$, where $y_1,y_2\in A$.
When $x_1,x_2\in\{0,1\}$, they are also in different connected components, because for an arbitrary subspace $A$ containing $y_1$ and $y_2$, $A$ has a separation $((X\cup\{y_1\})\cap A)\sqcup ((X\cup\{y_2\})\cap A)$, which indicates that $A$ is always disconnected.
For the third case, $A$ could be separated by $(A\setminus\{y_1\})\sqcup\{y_1\}$.

Then we intend to verify $Y$ is totally separated.
It follows from the hypothesis $X$ is an infinite set that for any point $y\in \{0,1\}$, $\{y\}$ is not open.